# How to Improve forecasting efficacy on an ARIMA model in Python

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, autoregressive, statsmodels

I am new to Python and pieced some code together to construct a monthly forecast.
The data is seasonal but the trend does not seem to be well defined.
I've read a lot of posts on the reasons why the forecasted line is straight but still hope to find a way to improve my model.
Thanks in advance

```py
import warnings
import itertools
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#from datetime import datetime
matplotlib.rcParams['axes.labelsize'] = 14
matplotlib.rcParams['xtick.labelsize'] = 12
matplotlib.rcParams['ytick.labelsize'] = 12
matplotlib.rcParams['text.color'] = 'k'

df = pd.read_csv('Book1---.csv')
#print(df.head())

#print(df['Month'].min(), df['Month'].max())
#print(df.dtypes)

df['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Month'], infer_datetime_format=True)
df = df.set_index('Month')
#print(df.index)

training_set = df[:'2021']
#print(training_set.index)

test_set = df['2022':]
#print(test_set.index)

training_set.plot(figsize=(15, 6))
#plt.show()


test_set.plot(figsize=(15, 6))
#plt.show()

from pylab import rcParams
rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 18, 8
decomposition = sm.tsa.seasonal_decompose(training_set, model='multiplicative')  #multiplicative     'additive'  
fig = decomposition.plot()
plt.show()
```

[image]

```py
p = d = q = range(0, 2)
pdq = [(1, 1, 0, 12)]

best_aic = float('inf')
best_model = None

for param in pdq:
    try:
        mod = sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(training_set,
                                            order=param,
                                            frequency='M', #'MS'  M//month end   MS//start month
                                            enforce_stationarity=False,
                                            enforce_invertibility=False)
        results = mod.fit()
        aic = results.aic
        if aic < best_aic:
            best_aic = aic
            best_model = results
    except:
        continue

print('ARIMA{} - AIC:{}'.format(param, best_aic))

mod = sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(
    training_set,
    order=(1, 0, 1),
    freq='MS',  # Explicitly specifying the frequency as 'MS' (monthly)
    enforce_stationarity=False,
    enforce_invertibility=False
)



results = mod.fit()
print(results.summary().tables[1])

results.plot_diagnostics(figsize=(16, 8))
plt.show() 

 

pred = results.get_prediction(start=pd.to_datetime('2016-01'), dynamic=False,exog=None)
pred_ci = pred.conf_int()
ax = training_set['1999':].plot(label='observed')
pred.predicted_mean.plot(ax=ax, label='One-step ahead Forecast', alpha=.95, figsize=(14, 7))
ax.fill_between(pred_ci.index,
                pred_ci.iloc[:, 0],
                pred_ci.iloc[:, 1], color='k', alpha=.2)
ax.set_xlabel('Date')
ax.set_ylabel('Units')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

```py
pred_uc = results.get_forecast(steps=72)
pred_ci = pred_uc.conf_int()

ax = training_set.plot(label='observed', figsize=(14, 7))

testSet = test_set.plot(label='Test Set', figsize=(14, 7))

pred_uc.predicted_mean.plot(ax=ax, label='Forecast')
pred_uc.predicted_mean.plot(ax=testSet, label='Forecast')

ax.fill_between(pred_ci.index,
                pred_ci.iloc[:, 0],
                pred_ci.iloc[:, 1], color='k', alpha=.25)
ax.set_xlabel('Date')
ax.set_ylabel('Units')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]